# Como apresentar uma lista por ordem alfabética provenientes de tabela mysql?

Tags: php

Com este código a ordem do menu das letras, enviadas pela tabela mysql, não aparece por ordem alfabética. A ordem que aparece actualmente é A D T V C S F M. Alguém me pode a ajudar a resolver este problema; ou seja, colocando a lista das letras por ordem alfabética?

**Código inicial da página:**

```
<?php 
include 'conn.php';

$letter = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn,htmlspecialchars(base64_decode($_GET["letter"])));

$sql = "SELECT Id,Palavra from dicionario_palavras where Pronta != 0 AND Palavra LIKE '".$letter."%'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(`Palavra`, 1, 1)) As abc from dicionario_palavras where Pronta != 0";

$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

?>
```

Comment: Já tentou adicionar o `order by` na sua SQL?

Comment: Sim eu já tenho o order By bem efectuado: us_DefinicoesPalavras(asc).

Comment: Onde está o ```ORDER BY ``` em sua query então ? Creio que um ```ORDER BY Palavra ASC ``` no final de sua query já resolve o problema.

Comment: Ok Leo... já resolvi. Muito obrigado pela dica. Eu publiquei aqui em baixo a solução.

Answer (score 1):

**Basta corrigir o código inicial da página na parte final, já testei e funciona:**

```
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(`Palavra`, 1, 1)) As abc from dicionario_palavras where Pronta != 0 ORDER BY abc";
```

Código errado:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(`Palavra`, 1, 1)) As abc from dicionario_palavras where Pronta != 0";
```